# How do I pass a string into subprocess module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, subprocess

I have an executable which will prompt for different options Eg; Executable: sample.exe On running sample.exe, I get a prompt to enter "help", "display", "quit" options.

I need to enter all these and check the output whether it has a valid output.

I am using subprocess to run the `sample.exe`.

I can pass the input using `subprocess.communicate(input='help')`

But other than quit all the option will not end the console and still waits for the input.

Tried code:

```
p_run = subprocess.Popen(['sample.exe'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p_run_out = p_run.communicate(input=b'help')
print(p_run_out)
```

Here it stuck in the `p_run_out = p_run.communicate(input=b'help')` as `sample.exe`  waits for another input. It only ends when we pass `quit`

How can I pass next command? How to get the output of previous command('help') ?

Comment: You're going to need to put some more clarity into your question and include the code you have tried and what your expected result is.

Comment: @PacketLoss I just updated with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass multiple commands and read the output of the first command only.

Updated code:

```
p_run = subprocess.Popen(['sample.exe'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p_run_out = p_run.communicate(input=b'help\nquit')[0]
print(p_run_out)
```